# Should I use IF or ELSE IF for the second statment

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I can't get this code to execute, I am sure that I wrote this incorrectly. Can someone assist please? Do you see something wrong?

```
if ($value1!=$value OR $value2 !=$value ) {
  echo "something ";
  exit();
}
else if ($value3!=$value OR $value4 !=$value) {
  echo "something";
  exit(); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Flagging to close because it is seeking debugging help ("Why isn't this code working?") without signs of effort.

Comment: @Jonathan signs of effort ? lmao . i attempted to write the script, what sort of effort are you looking for champ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do -- the comparisons between the variables and the variable names are not intuitive. **That said, `else` is unnecessary here.**

You only need `else` (or `elseif`) if you *don't* want the code in the `else` (or `elseif`) block to execute when the `if` statement is satisfied. Here, the `if` block contains an `exit()`. So, when the `if` condition is satisfied, no more code will be executed, regardless of whether it's in `if` or `elseif` blocks.

---

**Some more detail:**

Here's how `if` and `else` work:

```
if (condition) {
    // do this if condition is true
} elseif (condition_2) {
    // do this if condition is false but condition_2 is true
} else {
    // do this if neither condition nor condition_2 is true
}

/*
 * code here will execute whether or not either condition or condition_2 is true
 */
```

In your code, you short-circuit everything after the `if` block if the condition in your `if` is true. That is, if `$value1!=$value OR $value2 !=$value`, the script exits when you call `exit();`.